# Filter string array with substring

Tags: c#, arrays, linq

So I have these values in an Array:

```
1_642-name.xml
1_642-name2.xml
1_678-name.xml
1_678-name2.xml
```

I always only want the values with the highest number to be in my array. But i cannot seem to figure out how?

The string consists of these factors:

> 1 is a static number - And will always only be 1

> 642 or numbers between _ and - is an identity and can always get larger

> name.xml is always the same

I want to filter by the largest identity (678) in this case.

Ive tried something like this without luck:

```
string[] filter = lines.FindAll(lines, x => x.Substring(3, 3));
```

**Result:**

```
1_678-name.xml
1_678-name2.xml
```

Comment: Is the format of each of the string elements always the same? Have you tried parsing the different segments of each element? Is your number _always_ 3 digits?

Comment: Your question is vague, please explain in explicitly detail what you have and what you want

Comment: @gunr2171 Yes the format is always the same or now you say it- the middle number 678 can also have 4 numbers i guess.. Didnt think of that

Comment: @TheGeneral What is it that is vague? Im explaining i always want the values with the highest number?

Comment: There are 2 or 3 "numbers" in each string. With software, the more precise you can be about your requirements ("which _number_ do you want to order by") is the best. In this case, you mean to say "I want to return only entries where the number between the first "_" and the first "-" is largest in the set."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the number of characters in your format can vary easily, this is a great job for Regular Expressions. For example:

```
var input = "1_642-name2.xml";
var pattern = @"^\d+_(\d+)-.+$";
var match = Regex.Match(input, pattern);

match.Groups[1].Value; // "642" (as a string)
```

An explanation of the regex string can be found [here](https://regex101.com/r/4kec3D/1).

We can use that to extract various parts of each element of your array.

The first thing to do is find the max value, which, if we have this format:

```
#_###-wordswords
```

Then we want the number between the `_` and the `-`.

```
var list = new string[]
{
    "1_642-name.xml",
    "1_642-name2.xml",
    "1_678-name.xml",
    "1_678-name2.xml"
};

var pattern = new Regex(@"^\d+_(\d+)-.+$");
var maxValue = list.Max(x => int.Parse(pattern.Match(x).Groups[1].Value));
```

This finds "678" as the max value. Now we just need to filter the list to only show entries that have "678" in that format slot.

```
var matchingEntries = list
    .Where(x => pattern.Match(x).Groups[1].Value == maxValue.ToString());

foreach (var entry in matchingEntries)
{
    Console.WriteLine(entry);
}
```

The `Where` filters the list with your max value.

There are a good number of inefficiencies with this code. I'm regex parsing each value twice, and calculating the string equivalent of `maxValue` on each element. I'll leave fixing those as an exercise to the reader.

Comment: Make sure you add the correct using statements, such as `using System.Linq;` and `using System.Text.RegularExpressions;`. As for the unclear, I can only speculate that the original post wasn't clear on which "number" you wanted to order by. I know, from your point it make sense, but from us strangers that haven't used your code before, it's ambiguous.

Answer (score 1):

Just to provide an alternate to regular expressions, you can also simply parse each line, examine the number, and if it's the largest we've found so far, add the line to a list. Clear the list any time a larger number is found, and then return the list at the end.

A bonus is that we only loop through the list once instead of twice:

```
public static List<string> GetHighestNumberedLines(List<string> input)
{
    if (input == null || !input.Any()) return input;

    var result = new List<string>();
    var highNum = int.MinValue;

    foreach (var line in input)
    {
        var parts = line.Split('_', '-');
        int number;

        // Making sure we atually have a number where we expect it
        if (parts.Length > 1 && int.TryParse(parts[1], out number))
        {
            // If this is the highest number we've found, update
            // our variable and reset the list to contain this line
            if (number > highNum)
            {
                highNum = number;
                result = new List<string> {line};
            }
            // If this matches our high number, add this line to our list
            else if (number == highNum)
            {
                result.Add(line);
            }
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```